# Keep getting error "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I keep on getting this error and I am definitely not making an extreme amount of queries a day (maybe made around 5 before I got this error)

These are my two defs. One gets the calendar service and the other creates the events.

```
def get_calendar_service(self):
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', scopes)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service
```

This is where I try to create the new event. I first try to delete the event if it already exists since I want to recreate it every time someone wants to add it to their calendar.

```
@route("/add-google-calendar-event", methods=['POST'])
def add_event_to_google_calendar(self):
    appt_id = str(json.loads(request.data).get('appt_id'))
    appt = self.gcc.get_appointment_by_id(appt_id)
    start_time = appt.scheduledStart.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    end_time = appt.scheduledEnd.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    service = self.gcc.get_calendar_service()

    try:
        event = service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId=appt_id).execute()
    except:
        pass

    timezone = 'America/Chicago'

    event = {
        'id': appt_id,
        'eventId': appt_id,
        'summary': 'test test test',
        'location': 'test test',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': start_time,
            'timeZone': timezone,
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': end_time,
            'timeZone': timezone,
        },
        'attendees': [
            {'email': 'test@test.edu'},
        ],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': False,
            'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
            ],
        },
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    }

    try:
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        event = service.events().update(calendarId='primary', body=event, eventId=appt_id).execute()

    return ''
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I am using an OAuth 2.0 Client ID if that is helpful.

Comment: _maybe made around 5 before I got this error_ Then it sounds like 5 is the daily limit.

Comment: @JohnGordon According to Google Calendar Api's quota page, the quota is 1,000,000 queries per day

Comment: A million queries seems awfully generous for public usage... I assume that's the limit for _authenticated_ queries.

Comment: Hi @OldmanCoders , do you have your calendar API enabled in your project? You can check this by going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=[your project name] and looking there for the calendar API

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Yes the Google Calendar API is enabled there.

Comment: @OldmanCoders Could you try _rm token.pickle_ on your console and check if it keeps happening? Maybe you updated your cedentials or your scopes and you forgot to renew the token. Let me know if the issue keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

I think (at least sometimes) this error is misleading - which I think is the case here. You appear to be missing the UTC offset at the end of your `start_time` and `end_time` variables.

Basically your `start_time` and `end_time` variables are outputting like this: `2020-05-13T17:06:42`. 
And you need them to look like this:`2020-05-13T17:06:42-07:00` (Notice the -07:00 at the end)

Try replacing:

```
start_time = appt.scheduledStart.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_time = appt.scheduledEnd.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

With:

```
start_time = appt.scheduledStart.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
start_time = f'{start_time}-06:00'  # This is UTC-6 (America/Denver aka 'mountain-time')
end_time = appt.scheduledEnd.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_time = f'{end_time}-06:00'  # This is UTC-6 (America/Denver 'mountain-time')
```

If you need help generating the offset (instead of just hard-coding it), I recommend looking at the pytz package - then calling it with something like:

```
    time_zone = 'America/New_York'
    utc_now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(f'{time_zone}'))
    utc_offset = f'{str(utc_now)[-6:]}'  # Grab just the offset from the timestamp 
    time_start = time_start[:-6] + utc_offset
    time_end = time_end[:-6] + utc_offset
```

You can get a list of standard timezones from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List)